# IIF statement with specific and wildcard criteria

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am attempting to write a query that will return all results if a flag on a form is turned off and exclude a particular value if the flag is turned on. I've been searching but cannot find the exact syntax I need.

When I had 'Like' inside the iif statement (when it evaluated to False) no results were returned. When I moved the Like to the outside of the iif statement I will get the expected results when the check box is turned off. I cannot get any results if the flag is turned on.

Does anyone know how I need to write my iif statement to get all values if the flag is turned off and all values but "REPLN" if the flag is turned on?

*full statement added.

```
    SELECT MYTABLE.DPT_NUMBER, MYTABLE.VENDOR_ID AS [Vendor ID], MYTABLE.VENDOR_NAME AS [Vendor Name], Sum(MYTABLE.UNITS_ORDERED) AS [Units Ordered], Sum(MYTABLE.RECEIVED_QTY) AS [Units Received], IIf(Sum([MYTABLE]![RECEIVED_QTY])=0,0,([Units Received]/[Units Ordered])) AS [Received Fill Rate], Sum(MYTABLE.ASN_QTY) AS [ASN Ship QTY], Sum([MYTABLE]![ASN_QTY])-Sum([MYTABLE]![RECEIVED_QTY]) AS [Units In Transit], Sum([MYTABLE]![ASN_QTY])/Sum([MYTABLE]![UNITS_ORDERED]) AS [Fill Rate with In Transit], Sum([MYTABLE]![UNITS_ORDERED])-Sum([MYTABLE]![ASN_QTY]) AS [Units Open], MYTABLE.PO_TYPE
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE (((MYTABLE.PO_TYPE) Like IIf([Forms]![frmMain]![ReplnExclude]=True,([MyTable].[TYPE])<>"REPLN","*")) AND ((MYTABLE.DPT_NUMBER)=[Forms]![frmMain]![DeptNum]) AND ((MYTABLE.GROUP_ID)="RP10") AND ((MYTABLE.PO_EXP_RCT_DATE) Between [Forms]![frmMain]![StartDate] And [Forms]![frmMain]![EndDate]) AND ((MYTABLE.PO_HDR_STATUS)<>"Cancelled") AND ((MYTABLE.PO_DTL_STATUS)<>"Cancelled"))
GROUP BY MYTABLE.DPT_NUMBER, MYTABLE.VENDOR_ID, MYTABLE.VENDOR_NAME, MYTABLE.PO_TYPE
ORDER BY MYTABLE.VENDOR_NAME;
```

Comment: I see AND at the end of that so there is other criteria?   In short if you want to see it all, remove the were clause so WHERE  should be in your if statement or and.   If you post the rest of the sql we can probably give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your where clause you start with 'WHERE (((MYTABLE.PO_TYPE) Like' but give no criteria for what you are looking for and then do the iif statement to put another clause in.  I removed (((MYTABLE.PO_TYPE) Like from the statement below.

here we put the AND in the statement as we will only need the AND if it is true. Otherwise we just need a blank space to move to the next clause.

IIf([Forms]![frmMain]![ReplnExclude]=True,([MyTable].[TYPE])<>"REPLN AND",""))

So full

```
SELECT MYTABLE.DPT_NUMBER, MYTABLE.VENDOR_ID AS [Vendor ID], MYTABLE.VENDOR_NAME AS [Vendor Name], Sum(MYTABLE.UNITS_ORDERED) AS [Units Ordered], Sum(MYTABLE.RECEIVED_QTY) AS [Units Received], IIf(Sum([MYTABLE]![RECEIVED_QTY])=0,0,([Units Received]/[Units Ordered])) AS [Received Fill Rate], Sum(MYTABLE.ASN_QTY) AS [ASN Ship QTY], Sum([MYTABLE]![ASN_QTY])-Sum([MYTABLE]![RECEIVED_QTY]) AS [Units In Transit], Sum([MYTABLE]![ASN_QTY])/Sum([MYTABLE]![UNITS_ORDERED]) AS [Fill Rate with In Transit], Sum([MYTABLE]![UNITS_ORDERED])-Sum([MYTABLE]![ASN_QTY]) AS [Units Open], MYTABLE.PO_TYPE
FROM MYTABLE

WHERE IIf([Forms]![frmMain]![ReplnExclude]=True,([MyTable].[TYPE])<>"REPLN AND",""))  ((MYTABLE.DPT_NUMBER)=[Forms]![frmMain]![DeptNum]) AND ((MYTABLE.GROUP_ID)="RP10") AND ((MYTABLE.PO_EXP_RCT_DATE) Between [Forms]![frmMain]![StartDate] And [Forms]![frmMain]![EndDate]) AND ((MYTABLE.PO_HDR_STATUS)<>"Cancelled") AND ((MYTABLE.PO_DTL_STATUS)<>"Cancelled"))
GROUP BY MYTABLE.DPT_NUMBER, MYTABLE.VENDOR_ID, MYTABLE.VENDOR_NAME, MYTABLE.PO_TYPE
ORDER BY MYTABLE.VENDOR_NAME
```